# Changing ImageButton LayoutParams onAnimationEnd

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, android-button

I needed an EditText with three image buttons inside it, which I managed to create by using a relative layout and essentially placing the image buttons over the edittext. Something like:
[image: layout]

I am trying to animate the swapping of buttons IB1 and IB2 when the EditText is focused and swap them back again when it loses focus. I managed to do this too, but the problem comes when I try to update the buttons LayoutParams onAnimationEnd (otherwise the pixels change positions on the screen but the underlying views are still in their original positions).

The problem: When I update the ImageButton layoutParams that seems to trigger the EditText focus event again - once you tap the edittext widget the buttons start perpetually moving back and forth.

The relevant XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/commentView" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <EditText
   android:id="@+id/commentBox"
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:scrollHorizontally="true"
   android:paddingTop="10dp"
   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
   android:inputType="text" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:imeOptions="actionDone"
   android:paddingRight="100dp"
   android:paddingLeft="55dp"
   android:background="@drawable/comment"
   android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
   android:hint="Your comment..."
   />
   <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/commentBox"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sharebutton"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
   <ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/like"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/commentBox"
    android:src="@drawable/likebutton"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
   <ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/commentimagebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/share"
    android:src="@drawable/commentbutton"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

And the relevant code snippets:

```
commentBox.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                    RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) view.getParent();
                    ImageButton commentView = (ImageButton) parent.findViewById(R.id.commentimagebutton);
                    ImageButton likeView = (ImageButton) parent.findViewById(R.id.like);
                    if (hasFocus) {
                        swapViews(likeView, commentView);
                    }
                }
            });
```

And:

```
private void swapViews(final ImageButton firstView, final ImageButton secondView)
{
    //get view positions and calculate distance
    int secondPosition[] = new int[2];
    int firstPosition[] = new int[2];
    secondView.getLocationOnScreen(secondPosition);
    firstView.getLocationOnScreen(firstPosition);
    int moveDistance = Math.abs(secondPosition[0]-firstPosition[0]);

    //get LayoutParams
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams firstViewLayout = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) firstView.getLayoutParams();
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams secondViewLayout = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) secondView.getLayoutParams();

    //set up animations
    TranslateAnimation moveLeft = new TranslateAnimation( 0, -moveDistance, 0, 0);
    moveLeft.setDuration(1000);
    moveLeft.setFillAfter(true);

    TranslateAnimation moveRight = new TranslateAnimation( 0, moveDistance, 0, 0);
    moveRight.setDuration(1000);
    moveRight.setFillAfter(true);

    if (secondPosition[0] > firstPosition[0]) {
        moveLeft.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //change positions
                secondView.clearAnimation();
                secondViewLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, R.id.commentBox);
                secondViewLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, 0);
                secondView.setLayoutParams(secondViewLayout);
            }
        });

        moveRight.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //change positions
                firstView.clearAnimation();
                firstViewLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, 0);
                firstViewLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.share);
                firstView.setLayoutParams(firstViewLayout);
            }
        });

        //animate
        secondView.startAnimation(moveLeft);
        firstView.startAnimation(moveRight);
    } else {
        moveLeft.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //change positions
                firstView.clearAnimation();
                firstViewLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, R.id.commentBox);
                firstViewLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, 0);
                firstView.setLayoutParams(firstViewLayout);
            }
        });

        moveRight.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //change positions
                secondView.clearAnimation();
                secondViewLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, 0);
                secondViewLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.share);
                secondView.setLayoutParams(secondViewLayout);
            }
        });

        //animate
        secondView.startAnimation(moveRight);
        firstView.startAnimation(moveLeft);
    }
}
```

Note: I am using API level 10. I also tried using onClickListener on the EditText, but 1. the first tap on an edittext focuses it and only the second one is detected as a click and 2. it will not allow me to swap the buttons back once the edittext loses focus.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, adding additional rules to the `LayoutParams` will not remove the current rules, so you're left with:

```
<ImageButton
...
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/commentBox"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/commentBox"
...
 />
```

Either remove the older rule via `LayoutParams.removeRule()` (added in `API 17`), or try creating a new `LayoutParams` and see if that works.

Second, you'll probably want to call `view.requestLayout();` after changing its `LayoutParams`.